# How to remove activities above a certain activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

The app in our organization operates in KIOSK mode at various sites, beginning with a default activity, the splash screen, featuring an animated logo.

Following the splash screen, decisions are made based on specific parameters to determine the next activity.

The UserPanelActivity is constantly visible to the user, serving as the primary interaction point.

Users can navigate from the UserPanelActivity exclusively to the LoginActivity. Once logged in, the user is restricted to proceeding to the MainActivity.

After reaching the MainActivity, users can explore multiple activities based on their preferences.

Notably, users can only return from these subsequent activities to the MainActivity.

The objective is to find a method to close all activities opened after the MainActivity by removing them from the activity stack. Subsequently, the UserPanelActivity should be launched.

Comment: Have you tried with using `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` 
Like if you want to go in splash screen then add Flag in that intent

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to call `finishAffinity()` which would close the current Activity and remove everything from the backstack (including MainActivity). At the same time you can start a new instance of MainActivity passing it a param in its bundle that tells it that you want to open a particular Activity.

Answer (score 0):

using `finish()` will end the current activity and remove it from the backstack, so calling it after any navigation back to MainActivity in the code will make sure it cannot be accessed again by bad user flow.

e.g:

```
Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(progressIntent);
finish();
```

In your MainActivity be careful with overriding `onBackPressed()` if your backstack is always empty by design as it could lead to unwanted user flow :)